# How to save the last state of sliders after page reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have this network visualized using d3 and angular. Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/gty996/pen/rNVPPRK) to the visualization.
I wanted to save the last state of the network so that even if I refresh the page it will show the last state. But don't know how to do that.

I read that it can be done using `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` but I can't seem to figure it out for my visualization.

I tried this by setting my JSON data to the sessionStorage and then getting it:

```
 if (sessionStorage) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("myKey", myJSON.toString());
    }

 if (sessionStorage) {
        sessionStorage.getItem("myKey"); // {"myKey": "some value"}
    }
```

and I also tried it like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("networkGraph", networkGraph);
var networkGraph = localStorage.getItem("networkGraph");
```

but it's not working. Is this the right way to do it?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you need *sessionStorage* and not *localStorage*? In the case of *sessionStorage* saved data will be deleted when a browser tab with your app becomes closed.

You can write `localStorage.setItem('inputLayerHeight', vm.inputLayerHeight);` in your `onChange` handler to remember `inputLayerHeight` and `Number.parseInt(localStorage.getItem('inputLayerHeight')) || 15` to restore the `inputLayerHeight` at `value` property of `vm.inputLayerHeightSlider` object. The same approach can be used for the other values to keep.

Comment: thank you so much. This was very helpful! I appreciate it a lot.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is almost right. The only thing you need to change is the usage of localStorage. Simply add `window` or `$window` (more 'angulary' way to access window variable) variable like so:

```
$window.localStorage.setItem("networkGraph", JSON.stringify(networkGraph));
```

Also, I recommend using [angular-storage](https://github.com/auth0/angular-storage) if you're looking for an easy way to work with local storage. It makes things less painful :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be related to the way you are storing data on your local storage. You are saving data as a string however I think that d3 doesn't recognize strings as valid data options. So instead you should do something like this:

```
if (sessionStorage) {
    // Parse the data to a JavaScript Object
    const data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("myKey"));
} else {
// Fetch data...
// Set sessionStorage or localStorage
   sessionStorage.setItem("myKey", myJSON.toString());
}
```

You can rearrange the logic as it might suit you but the idea is that in the end you should use `JSON.parse()` when getting the data from storage.